# Which is the correct way to load data from a form, and then submit it

Tags: angular

[image]

I've made a diagram where I have a component A in which I input some data, then component B, which is the child of A.

Then I have a component C outside of A, B in which is in charge of submitting the form, and with another button loading data from component B.

The objective of component B is just displaying some information for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for a service, which is provided at root level, which will be responsible for owning the form data and propagate it to listeners.

This service should have a property, which is a BehaviorSubject for emitting changes to component B.

Component A can then push new values to this "formData" by calling `.next` on the BehaviorSubject.

In the end this service needs a function which submits the form and probably clears the formData.